# PIVOT function in Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am having a table containing the following data

```
SKU     Site  Code    Value
0890    50    BRAND   OMH
0890    50    CSBC    0763440890
0890    50    DWPS    0763440890
0890    50    DWS     0763440890
0890    50    DWSG    *
0890    50    EA      1
```

I am looking to convert it into a table like the following

```
SKU     BRAND   CSBC        DWPS        DWS         DWSG    EA
0890    OMH     0763440890  0763440890  0763440890  *       1
```

The version of the Oracle db we have is 10G so PIVOT is not useful yet.

Please help.

Comment: Is the entire set of possible Code identifiers known in advance? If not, you would need dynamic SQL (even WITH the `pivot` operator, even in Oracle 12.2, the current version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle 10 doesn't have pivot, so you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select sku,
       max(case when code = 'BRAND' then value end) as brand,
       max(case when code = 'CSBC' then value end) as CSBC,
       max(case when code = 'DWPS' then value end) as DWPS,
       max(case when code = 'DWS' then value end) as DWS,
       max(case when code = 'DWSG' then value end) as DWSG,
       max(case when code = 'EA' then value end) as ea
from t
group by sku;
```

Comment: Hey it's been two years since I got this answer and it truly helped a lot. Thanks!